# Emulator crashed on build of app after upgrading to Flutter 3.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, mobile-development

After upgrading to Flutter version 3.0, my project crashes on the first run. See the log below.
Please I need help.

Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...

✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.

Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:41249/xUB1prU2wGQ=/ws
I/Choreographer( 6207): Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
D/eglCodecCommon( 6207): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
D/EGL_emulation( 6207): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdfc05840: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc70e43c0)
D/eglCodecCommon( 6207): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
F/libc    ( 6207): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 6245 (1.raster), pid 6207 (wetinyouget_app)

---

Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:9/PSR1.180720.122/6736742:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 6207, tid: 6245, name: 1.raster  >>> com.example.wetinyouget_app <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
eax c82ff400  ebx ca35d508  ecx 00000000  edx c82e400c
edi 00000000  esi c82e4068
ebp c817fc08  esp c817fba0  eip c9d7d119
backtrace:
#00 pc 01830119  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#01 pc 018383b6  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#02 pc 018370bd  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#03 pc 01766b3b  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#04 pc 01764fc8  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#05 pc 017d73a9  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#06 pc 017d72d2  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#07 pc 017eab6c  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#08 pc 017eaa42  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#09 pc 01759062  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#10 pc 01758c7c  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#11 pc 0175948e  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#12 pc 017533cc  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#13 pc 015c74b5  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#14 pc 015c747b  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#15 pc 015c7436  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#16 pc 019e789d  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#17 pc 019e7bc9  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#18 pc 014ace7c  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#19 pc 018c1909  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#20 pc 018c1976  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#21 pc 018c193e  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#22 pc 018de9b8  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#23 pc 018dcfe7  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#24 pc 018ddd57  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#25 pc 018df15a  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#26 pc 014b1185  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#27 pc 018dd4fd  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#28 pc 018dd1c7  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#29 pc 018eeb7c  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#30 pc 014aab19  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#31 pc 014aec6d  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#32 pc 014aeb7e  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#33 pc 014b618a  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#34 pc 014b61b8  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#35 pc 00012a77  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::SimpleLooperCallback::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+39)
#36 pc 00013896  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+998)
#37 pc 0001340b  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+43)
#38 pc 0000e220  /system/lib/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+96)
#39 pc 014b60cd  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#40 pc 014aeb2c  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#41 pc 014ae654  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#42 pc 014b3e22  /data/app/com.example.wetinyouget_app-e_DWA-LGkZ1rYX5KIkh6xA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x147e000)
#43 pc 0008f065  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
#44 pc 0002485b  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Try to clean your `Emulator` from `Android Studio` go to `Device Manager -> Select Your Emulator -> right click it -> click wipe data or Cold Boot Now` then try to run your project again

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, then go to file --> Invalidate Cache & Restart.

**Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)**